# MS Access error "Unrecognized database format"

Tags: database, ms-access, format

I've a MDB file, it was working well, but suddenly it stopped working and gave the error message that says:

> Unrecognized database format

I tried a lot to retrieve the data but I got nothing, so if you have an application to fix corrupted MS Access files you can help me because the file has important data for me.

NOTE: Compact and repair service is not working, it gives the same error message.

Comment: When you say you have tried a lot to retrieve that data, what have you tried?

Comment: Okay, I tried to import the data into MSSQL or another MSAccess database, but the operation failed. I also tried to use most of repair and fix access databases apps but I failed because I have to buy the full version and the 90% of these apps are fake. I also tried some codes using C# but to run the code I have to connect to the database, but the connection failed because the mentioned error message which says "Unrecognized database format".